# Constant for polynomials of limited degree

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials

I'm trying to prove the following:

There exists a constant $C \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all polynomials $f(t) \in \mathbb{R}[t]$ of degree not greater than $ 2014 $ we have

$$ |f(10)| \leq C\sup\limits_{t \in [0,1]} |f(t)| $$

What surprises me, this task was mentioned at functional analysis class and I can't find a way to connect it to the subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the space of  polynomials of degree not greater than $2014$, for $f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{2014} a_n t^n$, we define its norm $$\|f(t)\|_1 = \sum_{n=0}^{2014}|a_n|$$

Since we are dealing with a finite dimensional space(in which all the norms are equivalent), this norm is equivalent to the norm

$$\|f(x)\|_2 = \sup_{t\in [0,1]}|f(t)|$$

in particular,  there exists $C>0$ such that $\|f(t)\|_1 \leq C\|f(t)\|_2$

Then remark that $|f(10)| \leq 10^{2014}\sum_{n=0}^{2014}|a_n|$, so

$$|f(10)| \leq 10^{2014} C\|f(t)\|_2= 10^{2014} C\sup_{t\in [0,1]}|f(t)|$$

Comment: Why not just define the norm $$||f(t)||=\sum_{n=0}^{2014}|10^na_n|$$ to begin with?

Comment: @Meelo yeah, it's an option

Comment: Thanks! I must have slept while equivalence of norms on a finite dimensional vector space was being proved

Comment: @Jytug You are welcome.